# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I'm practicing on a small store website project [this one](https://github.com/Eyongkevin/udacity-MyStore) but I'm having a problem with moving the items to the cart.

in the source code in file app/components/product-list/product-list.component.ts line 33 :

```
const cartIdx = cartProducts.findIndex(cart => cart.id === cartProduct.id)
```

when I do the same line I face the error:  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'

that's my code:

```
  onSubmit(cartItem: Product){
let toCartItem: CartItems[] = [];
let alertMessage: string = '';

const itemCount = this.selectedOption;
const cartItems: CartItems[] | [] = this.ProductserveService.getCartItems();


const itemID = cartItems.findIndex(cart => cart.id === cartItem.id)
toCartItem = cartItems;

if((itemID === -1) || (cartItems.length === 0)){
  toCartItem.push(Object.assign(cartItem, {option: itemCount}));

  alertMessage = `New Item '${cartItem.name}' added to cart`;
}

this.ProductserveService.addToCart(toCartItem);

alert(alertMessage);

this.printLocalData();
return false;}
```

anyone know why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code, you missed the datatype for **cart** inside your findIndex, make it `const cartIdx = cartProducts.findIndex(cart: CartProduct => cart.id === cartProduct.id)` from `const cartIdx = cartProducts.findIndex(cart => cart.id === cartProduct.id)`.